# How can I programmatically expand items in a TreeViewer?

Tags: treeview, jface, eclipse-plugin

I have a `TreeViewer` with an `ILazyTreeContentProvider`. I want to control the expansion of the top-level tree items: Initially they are unexpanded, but when an Action "Expand" is selected, the item should be expanded.

In the `action.run()` I currently do

```java
final EntityTreeNode projectNode = (EntityTreeNode) ((ITreeSelection) 
    viewer.getSelection()).getFirstElement();
// notify the content provider that the node should be expanded; it creates child nodes 
// and updates the child count and calls viewer.setChildCount
((LazyEntityModelViewContentProvider) viewer.getContentProvider()).expandProject(projectNode);
viewer.expandToLevel(projectNode, 2);                   
viewer.refresh(projectNode);
```

But the node is not expanded. It should at least change it's icon to show that it has children...

Comment: Try using a `TreePath` for the `expandToLevel` parameter rather than `projectNode`, it may help the viewer locate the node.

Comment: @greg-449: `viewer.expandToLevel( ((ITreeSelection) viewer.getSelection()).getPathsFor(projectNode)[0], 255);` does nothing.

Comment: I am talking about `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreePath` which you construct with a array of nodes from the root to the node.

Comment: @greg-449: `ITreeSelection.getPathsFor` returns that.